# How do conflicting CSS rules affect performance?

Tags: html, css, sass, less

I'm cleaning up some old CSS and I'm not sure I've commented out or removed all the conflicting rules. The project uses a lot of CPU for rendering, which is why I ask about what seems like a relatively small optimization.

**For example, if I had CSS like this, does the browser spend time on the rule `color: red` ?**

```css
span {
  color: red;
  color: black;
}
```

**Is  overriding within the same block (above) handled differently than the below:**

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
span {
  color: black;
}
```

Is there a good resource I can refer to for exactly how rules are processed from a CPU/GPU standpoint? There's plenty of info on the high level of how CSS rules are applied, but I'm wondering how much of a difference conflicting rules make. In my case, conflicting rules I may have overlooked are generally much more complicated than the simple example I gave above, involving multiple selectors, gradients, shadows, etc.

Comment: Some interesting reading here maybe although it's not about conflicting rules in particular https://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/

Comment: "Is there a good resource I can refer to for exactly how rules are processed from a CPU/GPU standpoint?" Probably not because this is an implementation detail that won't necessarily be the same even across browsers. Cascade resolution is a fundamental part of CSS processing (it's what the "C" stands for) and treating it like a performance liability is tantamount to treating CSS itself as a performance liability. Optimize your CSS not to avoid the cascade like the plague but to avoid unnecessary repetition (DRY).

Comment: @BoltClock, I'd settle for a resource that even addresses how any one browser (besides IE/Edge) handles this. That would provide useful insight. Optimizing is, of course, the best option, but this question is more, "how high on my list of a million priorities should this be?"

Answer (score 1):

Short: yes, it spend some time more to composition than paint (it will merge to one computed version which is visible in Chrome DevTool)

Long: It is more about size of CSS that you push on 3G devices rather than composition. Every bites mater as you push unnecessary code to everyone.

Main rule: Optimize that and other simple task by PostCSS, locally or in pipeline :) Or even by online processor.

Best: Write better code so less work afterwards :D